# How can i use "COALESCE(SUM..." in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

i try to use sum and Coalesce . How can i translate to linq?

```
 SELECT @SumQtyOut=COALESCE(SUM(Qty),0) FROM dbo.StockMovement WHERE FromLocationType=@FromLocationType AND
         * FromNo=@FromNo AND FromSeq=@FromSeq AND ItemTypeNo=@ItemTypeNo AND ItemID=@ItemID
```

i do sometihng :

```
 using (StockProcedureDataContext stock = new StockProcedureDataContext())
                {
                    SumQtyOut = from s in stock.StockMovements 
                                where s.FromLocationType == FromLocationType &&
                                s.FromNo== FromNo && 
                                s.FromSeq == FromSeq &&
                                s.ItemTypeNo == ItemTypeNo &&
                                s.ItemID == ItemID select 
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should yield the result you are looking for.

```
using (StockProcedureDataContext stock = new StockProcedureDataContext())
{
    var items = from s in stock.StockMovements 
                where s.FromLocationType == FromLocationType &&
                s.FromNo== FromNo && 
                s.FromSeq == FromSeq &&
                s.ItemTypeNo == ItemTypeNo &&
                s.ItemID == ItemID 
                select s.Qty ?? 0;
    SumQtyOut = items.Sum(x => x);
}
```

`select s.Qty ?? 0` returns 0 if `s.Qty` is `null`. `items.Sum(x => x)` summs up the quantities you have selected.